# How to change default "reading" program?

Tags: osx, printing, man, less

Right now, when I run `man (something)`, `less` is used to view it. However, on Mac OS X, I really like scrolling with touchpad instead of <kbd>up</kbd>/<kbd>down</kbd> or <kbd>page-up</kbd>/<kbd>page-down</kbd> buttons. Is there a way to just print text into the terminal instead of using `less` or `more`?

Comment: @peth The default one.

Comment: You can do it, but it'll make navigation and searching a pain. How about viewing the man pages in a GUI viewer? I don't know what's available in Carbon; in X there's `xman`, `tkman`, or whatever you have available. (Or there's Emacs, of course.)

Comment: `less` does scroll with the mouse scroll button for me. That maps to the touchpad of OSX I guess. So, maybe the terminal app has some kind of settings to allow this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Not sure about OSX, but hopefully it's Unix-y enough...

In your $HOME/.bashrc add the following line:

```
export MANPAGER=cat
```

If you want all of your paging programs to act in this way, set `PAGER` instead.  `man` will use `MANPAGER` if set, otherwise it falls back to `PAGER`, which if not set falls back to `more`.

Comment: Thanks, that works. However, do you know if there is a way to make scrolling start from the beginning of the document, not from the end? I guess this will bi tricky...

Comment: You mean you would like the text with the order reversed?  Last line first, and first line last?  If so, use `tac` ... and yes, that stands for `cat` backwards. Or do you mean that you want the scrollbar left so that the top of the document is showing?  If the latter, I have no idea.  That would be terminal (and thus MacOSX "Terminal" specific).

Comment: Second one. Yeah, that's a pity...

Answer (score 7):

To get the effect you want, where you get a man page in a separate window with the view starting at the first page, add the following to your `~/.bash_profile`:

```
function man {
    mf=`mktemp /tmp/$1-formatted-XXXXXXXXX`
    /usr/bin/man -t "$@" | pstopdf -i -o $mf
    mv $mf $mf.pdf
    open -W $mf.pdf
    rm $mf.pdf
}
```

You can log out and back in to activate it, or just reload the file with:

```
. ~/.bash_profile
```

The latter risks redefining things like the `PATH` variable with duplicate info.

This function overrides the `man` command, causing it to build a PDF-formatted version of the man page in a temporary file, open that in your PDF viewer (Preview, by default) and then remove the temporary PDF when you close the viewer. The idea being, your default PDF viewing program probably responds to the touchpad the way you want.

In order to get that last feature, where it removes the temporary PDF, I had to make `open(1)` wait until the PDF viewer closed before it proceeds. This means you can't continue to use your terminal window while the PDF stays open. One hack around this would be to remove the `-W` flag and follow the `open` command with something like `sleep 1`, which should be enough time for Preview to open. Another hack might be to replace the last line with something like this:

```
( sleep 60 ; rm $mf.pdf ) &
```

That schedules the `rm` command for 60 seconds in the future, certainly enough time.

Comment: Thanks, that's useful! Is there a way to adopt this beyond `man` command? i.e. set these actions as the default pager? (BTW, why remove the PDF if it is in `/tmp` folder anyway?).

Comment: Re: broadening it: you could install a text editor that adds a command line shortcut which also understands the `-` convention for getting input from stdin, like MacVim, then set the `PAGER` environment variable to something like `mvim -`. (TextWrangler also installs a command-line shortcut, but I don't know if it understands `-`.) The main problem with this is that some things expecting a "pager" also expect that they can do things like terminal escape sequences, for formatting. That's why I had to resort to PDF formatting for the "man" case.

Comment: Re: why remove the PDF? Just saving space and cleaning up after myself. Habit more than anything, really. If you don't mind all those temporary PDFs clogging up `/tmp` until something comes along to clean them up, go ahead and remove the `-W` and the `rm` command.

Comment: @Warren Young - Heresy! Sacrilege! If it cannot be easily viewed on 80x24 green phosphor, surely it isn't Unix.  All kidding aside, this is a great solution.  Upvote from me.

Comment: @Mark: Thanks. You already got +1 from me for your straightforward answer, before I added my tangent answer. :)

Answer (score 1):

Stumbled upon this page after a Google Search.

In response to the original question, `less -R` will enable mouse-wheel/touchpad scrolling.

In modern macOS the shell `$LESS` variable is already set to `-R` by default. If `$PAGER` is set to `less` and scrolling doesn't work for you, try running the following command:

```shell
export LESS="-R"
```

Concerning the [answer by Warren Young](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/15734/377345): mapping `man` to a shell function can be updated to use **`ps2pdf`** which is part of the Ghostscript package (which can be installed via Homebrew: `brew install ghostscript` ) and with a couple minor adjustments to the function (there is no longer flags for `-i` and `-o` and now uses uses `-` for stdin/stdout).

```shell
function man() {
    mf=`mktemp /tmp/$1-formatted-XXXXXXXXX`
    /usr/bin/man -t "$@" | ps2pdf - $mf
    mv $mf $mf.pdf
    open -W $mf.pdf
    rm $mf.pdf
}
```

Also probably worth noting that files in **`/tmp`** get cleared out automatically if they haven't been accessed in the last 3 days (at least this is the case on modern macOS).